# Abort for Postgres query with user defined function in C

Tags: c, postgresql

When i am aborting a postgres query which has a user defined function written in C, the context is not jumping to aborttransaction till i come out of one call for the user defined function.

To test this we can put something like sleep or while in the function and check that it does not come to abort processing when we are inside this function, is there any explanation for this? or this is unexpected?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, imagine it should jump while user function is still executing - how do you imagine it shall jump? Create another thread? Execute two code flows in parallel in the same thread? Please reformulate. Just now I can only find out that the described behavior is expected and well designed, and you want something too weird.

Comment: The user defined function in C is part of a dynamically loaded library, so shouldn't the SIGINT be handled there as well? Are you suggesting that the Function executes in a separate thread therefore it can't be interrupted? In a normal case when Control C is issued in psql the control jumps to abort transaction handler only in case when i am inside the C function it is not going.